# Proving that Levy-measures are $\sigma$-finite

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I have  a question that pertains to Levy measures and, more specifically, I would like to show that they are $\sigma$-finite. They are not finite in general and it is easy to provide examples of this.

A Levy measure on the real line is a measure $\nu $ such that 
$$\int (1 \wedge x^2)\, \nu(dx) < \infty. $$

How would like to prove that $\nu $ is $\sigma$-finite. I can prove that for every choice of
$a > 0 $ very small, it turns out that

$$\nu[(-a, a)^c] < \infty. $$
This is clearly a consequence of $\nu $ being a Levy measure, since we can choose $a < 1 $
and then $x^2 \wedge a^2 \le x^2 \wedge 1 $ which is $\nu$-integrable, by the very definition of $\nu. $ Finally, since
$$ \int (x^2\wedge a^2)\, \nu(dx) = \int_{(-a, a)} x^2\, \nu(dx) + a^2\int_{(-a, a)^c}\, \nu(dx) < \infty, $$
the conclusion follows.

What am I missing to try proving that $\nu $ is now actually $\sigma$-finite?

Thank you for any help.

Maurice

Comment: I do not think that it follows that levy measures are $\sigma$-finite. Consider $\nu =\infty \cdot \delta_0$ as a counter example, where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac measure at the origin. This example assumes that "$\wedge$" denotes the minimum.

Comment: The definition of the Lévy measure given above was not complete. If one defines $\nu$ on the whole space including zero, then it is required that $\nu\{0\}=0$.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I forgot to include that $\nu(\{0\}) $ is set equal to zero. Then I believe that it works. In fact now one can cover the real line with sets like $(-\infty, 1), \{[-1/n, -1/(n+1)]: n \in N\}, \{0\},\{[1/(n+1), 1/n]: n \in N\}, (1, \infty) $ and, since each of these intervals indexed by $n $ is contained in some $(-a, a)^c, $ it must have finite measure.

Comment: @Maurice Exactly. Alternatively, it is correct to say that $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$.